# Getting Error when I installed @mui/system then uninstalled it , later I keep getting this year

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2/Grid2.js 6:14-25 export 'createGrid' (imported as 'createGrid2') was not found in '@mui/system/Unstable_Grid' (module has no exports).
```

Getting Error when I installed `@mui/system` then uninstalled it , later I keep getting this year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error you're encountering, you can follow these steps:

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder in your project.
2. Clear the cache by running the following command:

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
3. Install all the dependencies again by running:

   ```
   npm install
   ```

This will remove any remnants of the previously installed `@mui/system` package and reinstall all dependencies from scratch. Hopefully, this resolves the error you're facing.